# "Disconnect" Android Studio Profiler from device

Tags: android, android-studio

Does anyone know of a way to stop the Profiler from... profiling ... in Android Studio 2.4+?

It uses a ton of the host machine's CPU when I'm not actually using it. I know I can restart Android Studio but I should not have to resort to that to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using android studio version `3.0 beta-4`

you can easily stop the profiler by clicking on the red X.
[image]

or if you are using 2.3 just check the pause button.
[image]

Comment: Durrr... guess I'm out of luck in 2.4 then. :-( . Thanks!

Comment: It seems that unchecking "Live" just pauses the graph, not the actual collection of data, as far as I can tell.

Comment: interesting. why are you still using 2.4 it's neither the latest version nor the stable one. google just abandoned it in favor of 3.0 as they this it's a major update from 2.3

Comment: In Android Studio 3.1, the button isn't a red X any more - instead, it says "End Session".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an app which I was profiling. The app crashed, and then each time i started a normal debug or run session, the profiler would kick into life and cause it to crash.

There were no active buttons to end the profiler session (apart from restarting Android Studio). The only way i found was to start a normal debug session, the profiler then started which also enabled the red stop icon. Clicking it while the app was running then detached the profiler session for good.